# How to add array to parameter with function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, parameters

I am very new to programming and I am wondering if anyone can help me with this.

I am trying to make a pop up page. 
I set variables for each click area which I set each area with `div` and placed with css. 
Also for each pop up image which I put div id on each image on html and set `display = "none"` on css.
I want to make a function that shows one image on touchend and hide other images at the same time.

Could you help me with my code?

```
var pop = new Array("pop1","pop2","pop3","pop4","pop5","pop6");    
var clickArea = new Array("click1","click2","click3","click4","click5","click6");    
function diplay(click,show,hide){   
    click.addEventListner("touchend",function(){    
       show.style.display = "block";    
       hide.style.display = "none";    
    });    
};    
display("click[0]","pop[0]","pop[1,2,3,4,5]");
```

Comment: This jQuery plugin does what you're looking for: http://tosrus.frebsite.nl/examples.php . The site has instructions.

Comment: Thank you! I will use this when I study jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different issues with your code.

1. You used strings instead of the actual code structure references while calling `display`. I see that you mean for these to reference the element `id`s, but you must first get the element with `document.getElementById(...)` or jQuery's `$("#...")`.
2. In the `pop` and `clickArea` arrays, you used strings, which do not have the `.style` object. You need to reference the elements themselves.
3. Your code structure is not designed to handle arrays.
4. You need to define the `addEventListener` *before* you need the function handler to be called. You do not want this every time.
5. The `click` argument in the `display` function is redundant, as it is never called.
6. You are using jQuery. You should have stated this! (but you're forgiven)  :)
7. You can't reach into arrays with the syntax `arrayName[#,#,#]`.
8. You misspelled "display". Whoops!
9. The arrays are redundant, since the code needed to be restructured.

First, in order to address Point #4, we need this code to run when the DOM has finished loading:

```
var clickArea = new Array("click1","click2","click3","click4","click5","click6");
clickArea.each(function(id){
    $("#"+id)[0].addEventListener("touchend", display);
});
```

Next, we need to fix the issues with your code. They're explained above.

```
var pop = new Array("pop1","pop2","pop3","pop4","pop5","pop6");
function display(event){
    var indx = Number(event.target.id.split(/\D/i).join(""));
    $("#pop"+indx)[0].style.display = "block";
    pop.each(function(ide) {
        if (ide.split(/\D/i).join("") != indx-1) {
            $("#"+ide)[0].style.display = "none";
        }
    });
};
```

Otherwise, great job! All of us started out like this, and believe in you! Keep it up!
P.S. You can set arrays like this `[ ? , ? , ? , ? ]` instead of this `new Array( ? , ? , ? , ? )`.

Comment: I echo @fond42518's comment about using Array literals - in fact, you should almost NEVER use `new Array()` over just creating array literals `[]`.

Comment: Thank you very very much!!  I think someone deleted my title part saying Javascript. I haven't tried jQuery yet. It seems like more simplified in jQuery. Can I do the same thing with Javascript?

Comment: Yes, you can do the exact same things in plain JavaScript, although the element id selectors are `document.getElementById(...)` instead of `$(#...)`, and the plain JavaScript method returns only one element, rather than an array. Also, you'd have to use a `for` loop instead of jQuery's `.each` function.

Comment: Thank you! I will try JS and jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using `for` loops instead of methods of *Arrays* etc

Start off by defining everything you can

```
var popup_id = ["pop1", "pop2", "pop3", "pop4", "pop5", "pop6"],
    popup_elm = [], // for referencing the elements later
    area_id = ["click1", "click2", "click3", "click4", "click5", "click6"],
    area_elm = [], // for referencing the elements later
    i; // for the for -- don't forget to var everything you use
// a function to hide all popups
function hideAll() {
    var i; // it's own var means it doesn't change anything outside the function
    for (i = 0; i < popup_elm.length; ++i) {
        popup_elm.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
// a function to attach listeners
function listenTouch(area, popup) {
    area.addEventListener('touchend', function () {
        hideAll();
        popup.style.display = 'block';
    });
    // we did this in it's own function to give us a "closure"
}
```

Finally we are ready do begin linking it all to the *DOM*, I'm assuming the following code is executed after the elements exist in the browser

```
// setup - get Elements from ids, attach listeners
for (i = 0; i < popup_id.length; ++i) {
    popup_elm[i] = document.getElementById(popup_id[i]);
    area_elm[i] = document.getElementById(area_id[i]);
    listenTouch(area_elm[i], popup_elm[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did get variables for each pop with document.getElementById but I didn't know that I can use for loop. I was using 6lines to get variables for each pop. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot treat strings as html elements.

Assuming there are elements with click area ids in the page, you may do something like (once the document is ready).

```
var popEls = pop.map(function (id) { return document.getElementById(id) });

clickArea.forEach(function (id) {
 var clickAreaEl = document.getElementById(id);
 clickAreaEl.addEventListener('click', onClickAreaClick);
});

function onClickAreaClick() {
    var clickAreaNum = +this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0],
        popIndex = clickAreaNum - 1;

    popEls.forEach(function (popEl) {
        popEl.style.display = 'none';
    });

   popEls[popIndex].style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!wow it is amazing that I can learn a lot from your code. Thank you thank you thank you!!